# Which language is better for raspberry pi compute module for image processing?(Python/CPP/JAVA)

Tags: opencv, compute-module

As I want to  develop product using raspberry pi Compute module.
Which language is better for image processing if I am using OpenCV??
Camera in project is steady taking video & doing processing...

Comment: Given we know nothing about the detail of your image processing it's hard to see how we can answer.

Comment: C++ is always the winner, on any platform and any OS. You are asking the wrong question and researching in the wrong direction. First write the software so its fast, then find your platform. Because its possible that you may benefit from x86 technology that ARM does not offer so its possible you could use Intel Graphics better than VideoCore due to using SSE which ARM does not have. You first need to decide that. Good luck.. you gonna need it.

Comment: Thanks....My platform is fix which is raspberry pi(for this project only). But after implementation of this if I want to choose platform other than raspberry pi then which one is good??

Comment: If you define better in more detail Im sure someone could answer your question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

All the languages that you mentioned can be used for image processing using opencv. It depends on the requirements of the application and your skills in a particular programming language.

If you are a beginner then I suggest Python, even though it is slow, it is easy to learn and reduces the complexity of the code. Also Python has various other libraries like machine learning which will make your application open for future modifications.

If performance is what you need then go for C++, but you need to have good knowledge of programming and since opencv library is built using C and C++, at the end of the day whichever language you use they depend directly or indirectly on C++

Java on the other hand is not usually preferred for image processing using opencv because of it is slower and instable

Comment: Hello and welcome! Given that in OpenCV, all algorithms are implemented in C++, the key aspects you stress here ("Python is slow") are not of significance.

Comment: Compared to c++ python is slow

Comment: Thanks I am beginner & know python. Please suggest me the steps/good links for OpenCV + Python + Image Processing

Comment: You can refer sentdex tutorials, they are good just google 'sentdex image processing'